# Quick jQuery Question

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

`<a href="javascript:$('#searchPost').submit()">Search</a>`

This submits my search form. I'm trying to keep it from submitting when empty. I know that'll be difficult to do inline, but when I tried to take the JS code out of the link, it ceases to work, even when the inline code calls a function outside of the link.

I was told to use this code:

```
$('#searchPost').submit(function(event) {
    if ($(this).find('#searchBox').val() == '') {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

But I'm not sure where to put it to make it work. Of course, inline, that code doesn't do what I want it to. I put that completely in the head of my document and it didn't change much either. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){});` or short hand of `$(function(){});`

Comment: Nothing to feel sorry about, just glad I could help with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).find('#searchBox').val() == '') {
     return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the function:

```
return false;
```

[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to trap the $('#searchPost').click() event, not the submit() event.

Try trapping $.click(), then checking the val(), then conditionally executing $.submit().

Make sure $('#searchPost') exists too...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your code, I'd say a safe bet would be to place that code after the jQuery script and after the form.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap it in a DOMready handler, this is the easiest way to do it with jQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $('#searchPost').submit(function(event) {
       if ($(this).find('#searchBox').val() == '') {
          event.preventDefault();
       }
   }); 
});
</script>
```